# JQGrid sortableRows change sorting column values to match new order

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-sortable

So I'm using JQGrid to produce a table. The data is read from a database and the table is populated via JSON. Once the table is rendered all the sorting and editing is done locally until the data is saved backed into the database. I am using the sortableRows function so that i can drag and drop and reorder the rows; it is working as expected except I also want the values of a specific columns to change based on the new order. I have been following this example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortaleRows1.htm) as is does exactly what I'm trying to do, but looking at the source code as not done me much good. I believe it has to do with the `update()` function.

I want the values of the Display Order column to be renumbered starting from 0 going by multiples of 10 depending on the new order the the rows. like is in my example [image]

Can anyone give me some insight in the right direction?

Here is my JQGrid code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'/WEB_META_CONFIG/meta/record?meta_type=${meta_type}&plan_id=${plan_id}',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:[
                    'Display Order', 
                    'Field Name', 
                    'Field Label', 
                    'Meta Type', 
                    'Display Control', 
                    'plan id',
                    'lov',
                    'rounding formula',
                    'units',
                    'hrms data type',
                    'conversion data type',
                    'modified by',
                    'capability',
                    'field width',
                    'field validation message',
                    'field null string',
                    'field ineligibility tag',
                    'hard validation logic',
                    'hard validation message',
                    'soft validation logic',
                    'soft validation message',
                    'attribute1',
                    'attribute2',
                    'attribute3',
                    'attribute4',
                    'attribute5',
                    'field required',
                    'field length',
                    'field format',
                    //'calculation',
                ],
        colModel:[
            {name:'display_order',index:'display_order', align:'center', width:'100',sorttype:'int'},
            {name:'field_name',index:'field_name', align:'left', editable:true},
            {name:'field_label',index:'field_label', align:'left', editable:true},
            {name:'meta_type',index:'meta_type', align:'center', width:'60'},
            {name:'display_control',index:'display_control', align:'left',editable:true},
            {name:'plan_id',index:'plan_id', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'lov', index:'lov', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'rounding_formula', index:'rounding_formula', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'units', index:'units', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'hrms_data_type', index:'hrms_data_type', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'conversion_data_type', index:'conversion_data_type', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'modified_by', index:'modified_by', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'capability', index:'capability', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_width', index:'field_width', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_validation_message', index:'field_validation_message', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_null_string', index:'field_null_string', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_ineligibility_tag', index:'field_ineligibility_tag', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'hard_validation_logic', index:'hard_validation_logic', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'hard_validation_message', index:'hard_validation_message', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'soft_validation_logic', index:'soft_validation_logic', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'soft_validation_message', index:'soft_validation_message', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'attribute1', index:'attribute1', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'attribute2', index:'attribute2', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'attribute3', index:'attribute3', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'attribute4', index:'attribute4', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'attribute5', index:'attribute5', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_required', index:'field_required', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_length', index:'field_length', align:'left',hidden:true},
            {name:'field_format', index:'field_format', align:'left',hidden:true},
            //{name:'calculation', index:'calculation', align:'left',hidden:true},
            ],
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,40],
        shrinkToFit : true,
        loadonce: true,
        gridview: true,
        //editurl:'/WEB_META_CONFIG/meta/record',
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit:'clientArray',
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'display_order',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption:"${plan_id} - ${meta_type}",
        emptyrecords: "Empty records",
        sortable:true,
        jsonReader : {
            repeatitems: false,

        },
        beforeSelectRow : function(rowid) {return false;},
        ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow,iCol){
            $('#grid').editCell(iRow, iCol, true);
        },
    });

    $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});
    $('#grid').jqGrid('sortableRows', {
        update:function(ev, ui){
            var item = ui.item[0], ri = item.rowIndex, itemId = item.id;
        }
    });

    $("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
            {   caption:"Save", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk", 
                onClickButton: save,
                position: "last", 
                title:"", 
                cursor: "pointer"
            } 
    );

    function save(){

        //var data = $('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData');
        var data = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            delete data[i]["_id_"];
        }


        $.ajax({
            type :"POST",
            url : "/WEB_META_CONFIG/meta/record/save",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data, function(key, value){
                                    return (value == null) ? "" : value;
                                    }
            ),
            success: function(){
                alert('Save Successfully');
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to call the remapColumns function to do this as part of your update call.  The tricky part is finding what the new order should be based on the user changes you have described.  This new order is passed into the array as the first part of the call.  See [jqgrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Amethods)

```
$("#grid").remapColumns([1,3,2],true,false);
```